# Битая кодировка после обработки html страницы сервлетом

Tags: java, html, servlet

Есть некоторая html страница, у которой выставлена кодировка, как-то так:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Если страницу открыть в браузере, то кирилица отображается корректо, если ее вызвать уже в приложении, когда ее отдает сервлет, то кирилица отображается некорректно, из-за чего?
Контроллер:

```
    @Controller
    public class mainController {
        @GetMapping
        public String main_page(HttpServletResponse response) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
            return "main_page";
        }
```

Страница:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Number parse</title>
    </head>
    <body>

Русский текст
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: должно быть `<meta charset="UTF-8">` [документация](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp) , а по вопросу добавьте минимальный пример html страницы и сервлет, на котором это воспроизводится

Comment: у меня в html кодировка выставлена

Comment: в jsp странице высталено `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf8" pageEncoding="utf8"%>` ? Добавьте минимальный пример страницы на которой не корректная кириллица

Comment: у меня нет jsp страниц. пример добавил

Comment: тогда нужно выставить [ThymeleafViewResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39809246/6752984), для поддержки utf8

Comment: Спасибо! Ответ нашел тут:
http://forum.thymeleaf.org/UTF8-charset-problem-td3608879.html